# get ngAnimate working in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am following the following link to get angular animations working in the app:

http://angularanimation.ya.com.tr/start.html

I have animate.css in my css folder and link to it in index.html.

Also, I have `ngAnimate` as a dependent module in app.js

I tried to use an animation in my html:

```
<ion-view class="slide-from-top">
<ion-content>

<div class="contentArea">  
        <form action="#">

                                <div class="row">

                <label>The Italian Melt</label>
                <input class="field" type="text" value="160.00">
                <input class="number" type="text" value="1">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
                            </div>


      <div class="row">

                <label>The Italian Melt</label>
                <input class="field" type="text" value="160.00">
                <input class="number" type="text" value="1">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <label>The Italian Melt</label>
                <input class="field" type="text" value="160.00">
                <input class="number" type="text" value="1">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
            </div>

            <hr>
                <div class="row text">
                    <div class="col-33">Subtotal</div>
                    <div class="col-75">Rs. 210.00</div>
                 </div>
            <div class="row text">
                    <div class="col-33 blueText">Discount</div>
                    <div class="col-75 blueText">Rs. 42.00</div>

            </div>
                <div class="row text">
                    <div class="col-33">Delivery Fee</div>
                    <div class="col-75">Rs. 10.00</div>
                </div>
                 <hr>
                  <div class="row text">Total will refund off</div></br>
                   <div class="row text">
                   <div class="col-33 totalBig">Total</div>

                    <div class="col-75 totalBig">Rs. 178.00</div>
                </div>
                  <hr>
                    <form action="#">
                        <div class="customRow">
                     <div class="row coupon">

                        <label>Coupon</label>
                        <input class="couponField" type="text">
                        <button class="applyBtn">Apply</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
   <p class="row redText">Minimum Order :  Rs. 500/-</p>

    </div>
<button class="button-checkout">Proceed to Checkout <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> >></button>

</ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

Infact, when I go to console,

I see this:

[image]

How do I get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pleas check https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

### Dynamic Animation

You have to call animation function like

```
<ion-view class="myAnimation">
    <ion-content>
        ....
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and add class when page is loaded

```
$('#myAnimation').addClass('animated shake');
```

and after animation finish you have to remove class which is added to div so again animation works without refresh page. for that you have to do that

```
$('#myAnimation').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', removeClass);

function removeClass()
{
    $('#myAnimation').removeClass('animated shake');
}
```

This way is dynamic but you can also set as static in html like

### Static

```
<ion-view class="animated shake">
    <ion-content>
        ....
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: But the link does not say so at all. Have you checked the link?

Comment: Yes, and it asks for that step when it has to be done dynamically.

Comment: Yes and please check answer again i add some more things to it. which needed for that

Comment: But I believe there are other ways with which I would need to have this as a step, Isn't it?

Comment: Okay, i added animated shake and that works , but how do I add slidedown animation statically?

Comment: You can find classes here for different animation https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Of course I did and that did not work.I would not ask without trying something very basic.

Comment: It does. I tried slideInDown and it does not. I can see class with name slideInDown in animate.css and yet is not being applied.

Comment: animated slideInDown is whole class. please add animated class then slideInDown

Comment: Could you please update the link to show what exactly you mean by that?

Comment: Awesome . It worked. Could you please let me know what was wrong with using slideInDown and what was different in FadeInDownBig so that I don't end up making the same mistake again?

Comment: Really i dont know i think something wrong in our code because this code works in their code but i just find alternate of slideInDown. please vote if i help you

Comment: Okay, I understand that I was not adding the class animated. I have one more query though. I see people using animation class name.ng-enter and animation class name.ng-enter active e.t.c, How is this different from adding these animation classes?Also, I want this to go up on click of a button , do I accomplish that using those css classes?

Comment: slideInDown also started working once I added animated class before it.

Comment: have to add animated class before animation class

Comment: we can make animation in ng-enter or in ng-leave etc etc but it hard for starter like me