# Hide Animation not working in Ionic

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, ionic-framework

I am learning Ionic framework and I am trying to add show\hide fade animation to 'card' using CSS. I have defined 1-second duration transition animation but the target element simply disappears after 1 second of click the button without any animation.

here is my code

**HTML**

```
<ion-list class="card step-card" ng-show="s1">
      <ion-item>Add some salt</ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-button-right">
        &nbsp;
        <button class="button" ng-click="showNextStep()">Next</button>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**CSS**

```
.step-card
{
    transition: all linear 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
.step-card.ng-hide-add
{
    opacity: 0;
}
.step-card.ng-hide-remove
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngAnimate'])
```

**> ionic info** output

```
******************************************************                                                        
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,                                                           
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:                                                   

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`                                 
 Install ios-sim to deploy iOS applications.`npm install -g ios-sim` (may require sudo)                       
 Install ios-deploy to deploy iOS applications to devices.  `npm install -g ios-deploy` (may require sudo)    

******************************************************                                                        

Your system information:                                                                                      

Cordova CLI: Not installed                                                                                    
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8                                                                                      
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4                                                                                  
ios-deploy version: Not installed                                                                             
ios-sim version: Not installed                                                                                
OS: Windows 10                                                                                                
Node Version: v7.1.0                                                                                          
Xcode version: Not installed                                                                                  


******************************************************                                                        
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,                                                           
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:                                                   

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`                                 
 Install ios-sim to deploy iOS applications.`npm install -g ios-sim` (may require sudo)                       
 Install ios-deploy to deploy iOS applications to devices.  `npm install -g ios-deploy` (may require sudo)    

******************************************************
```

Please help me fix the problem.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I think there might be some issue between ngAnimate and Ionic. Please visit a prior post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496394/get-nganimate-working-in-ionic-app to try and resolve these issues.

Comment: Tried animate.css way but still same thing is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation usually works in Ionic. However in my case it was not working because I was trying to animate an `<ion-list>` element using `ng-show` attribute.

```
<ion-list class="card step-card" ng-show="s1">
      <ion-item>Add some salt</ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-button-right">
        &nbsp;
        <button class="button" ng-click="showNextStep()">Next</button>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I do not know exact reason but I cannot make it animate. 
So, I found another way and then it works perfectly. I changed above code to something like this:

```
<div class="step-card" ng-show="s1">
    <ion-list class="card">
      <ion-item>Add some salt</ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-button-right">
        &nbsp;
        <button class="button" ng-click="showNextStep()">Next</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

As you can see, instead of animating `<ion-list>`, I encapsulated it in a `<div>` and now I am animating the `<div>` using `ng-show` attribute. (Now, you can use `.ng-hide-add` `.ng-hide-remove` in CSS to animate. Or, famous `animate.css` file for awesome animations)

Also, as pointed out by OClyde there was no need to explicitly include `ngAnimate` as dependency. Its already included in Ionic.

An advice: If you are trying to learn animation in Ionic first try them on simple html elements like `<div> <span>` etc before jumping to Ionic specific tags like `<ion-list>`.

For a simple animation working example you could refer OClyde answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to include ngAnimate explicitly as Ionic does include it already.

Prepared a little playground example, in short just using `.ng-hide` does the trick here:

```
.animate-hide 
{
  /*
   * ...
   */

  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s;

  opacity: 1;
}

.animate-hide.ng-hide 
{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Check this link for the working example: http://play.ionic.io/app/6927b6ff5207

EDIT: Stripped down my code to use $scope instead of controllerAs syntax as it might be more straight forward though. To reproduce this example locally, just start a blank Ionic app and add the following:

In your template, add this button and this div:

```html
<!-- omit this outer div if you load the controller in your routing -->
<div ng-controller="AwesomeCtrl">    

  <button 
    class="button button-block"
    ng-class="{
      'button-dark' : hide,
      'button-assertive' : !hide
    }"
    ng-click="toggle()">
    Toggle hiding
  </button>

  <div
    class="animate-hide"
    ng-show="!hide"
    >
    Mew where is my slave? I'm getting hungry yet tuxedo cats always looking dapper jump launch to pounce upon little yarn mouse, bare fangs           at toy run hide in litter box until treats are fed but my slave human didn't give me any food so i pooped on the floor. Plan steps for             world domination. Go into a room to decide you didn't want to be in there anyway wake up human for food at 4am and under the bed, for              leave dead animals as gifts. 
  </div>

</div>
```

In your css file add this:

```css
.button
{
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
  -o-transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: all ease-in-out .5s;
}

.animate-hide 
{
  margin: 24px 0;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black;

  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s;

  opacity: 1;
}

.animate-hide.ng-hide 
{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

And finally, define a controller as follows:

```
app.controller('AwesomeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.hide = false;

  $scope.toggle = function() 
  {
    $scope.hide = !$scope.hide;
  }

})
```

That should be all you need to reproduce.

Comment: Your demo works online but its not working when I do the same in my Ionic app. Is there any way I can download your demo and run it on my PC to see if there is any problem with my PC or Ionic version?

Comment: Edited my answer to include all steps for reproducing locally. Unfortunately Ionic playground does not have a download button yet. ;)

Comment: I exactly followed your step to reproduce the code and I can see that now when I run it from my PC the div shows and hide on button click but without animation. Also, the color of button changes from red to black but at once without animation (i.e. red does not gradually changes to black).

Comment: Atleast now I can confirm that error is somewhere else. I see following in Chrome console            Error: GET http://localhost:8100/cordova.js 
?ionicplatform=android:91       Error: GET http://localhost:8100/cordova.js 
?ionicplatform=android:91            Error: GET http://localhost:8100/cordova.js 
ionic-lab:182             Error:GET https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED(anonymous function) @ ionic-lab:182(anonymous function) @ ionic-lab:183

Comment: i have +1 your answer for working demo and your efforts. Will accept it once it works on my PC

Comment: Not sure though.. might be necessary to add the protocol for google-analytics to reference it correctly: `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` but not sure if a not resolved script would omit animations. Could you add the protocol for GA and additionally run `ionic info` in your console and add the output to your question? Just to have the complete information on used Cordova & Ionic version ;)

Comment: I have updated my question showing output for command 'ionic info'

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to bother you again, but have you executed this in your project folder? The `Ionic Framework Version` is missing in the output which would be quite interesting as well!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128078/discussion-between-prodev-and-oclyde).

Comment: No, I executed it from where my ionic CLI is installed. I have installed ionic 2 days ago so I guess it must be using latest framework (version 1.x)

Comment: Shouldn't we really move over to chat as proposed? ;)

Comment: One good news. Your demo code which I reproduced started to work as expected on its own. I just ran it again today without any editing. Hahaha. Whats going on!!!